# Centralize business logic used by C# and tsql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

In our application we are using custom rounding which is defined by our users and the rounding rules per minute are stored in a database table which can be changed at any moment by any user.

We have the same code both in C# and Sql. In C# we store them in cache for faster read when we need to use them and in Sql we join with the rounding table to find the correct rounding rule for that minute.

So in order to centralize the logic we thought using a view both in the app and in sql which will join the original table with the rounded rules table and add the two new columns with the rounded values. But that's for already existing records and sometimes we need to do a rounding on values on the go, so using the view is not the workaround that we hoped.

The latest thought of handling this is using an sqlclr function but if it's a function it will be called for every row of the select with the original table to get the rounded values and that will not be efficient as the join that we do on the sql side. Is there a way of using an sqlclr function for this scenario or is there a better way of centralizing the business logic?

Ex. from the database side:
[image]

This is the older approach, now we have a view that returns all the columns from the Clockings table plus the rounded columns for start and end, but it's not covering all the cases that we need in C#.

Sorry for not being able to send link to the fiddle, sqlfiddle is not working properly at the moment.

Comment: Sample data, use case, and desired results would be helpful

Comment: Can different users apply different rules to the same data for the same time interval? Presumably you have values stored with date/times and need to be able to apply the rounding that was applicable at the time the data was stamped. How does all this affect aggregations, or do you avoid them? Can the data values and/or date/times be updated or are they write-once? ... .

Answer (score 1):

The typical scenario for centralizing business logic has that logic defined in the app code, in which case it can make sense to use SQLCLR to have that logic in both place at once.

But in this case the logic is in the database already. And even if not for the fact that the UDF would be called per row (since it cannot be marked as `IsDeterministic = true` ), it probably still wouldn't make sense to do as you would be in the Database, calling into .NET for no other reason than to reach back into the Database for something that was already accessible.

It would seem that you either:

1. Reevaluate your need for centralizing in the first place. No explicit reason was ever given, and if it is merely to "feel" better about not having it in two places, then the benefits might not outweigh the costs,

   OR:
2. If you *really* want to centralize, then do just that and have the app layer call into the DB for all calculations using these rounding rules (i.e. not just calling the DB for the rules and then calculating in the app layer). Force the app layer to go through the same logic that your T-SQL is going through. This would work, but again, the benefits might not outweigh the costs.

Comment: It's not crucial for us to make it centralized but when it's in one place it's easier for the new developers to know how to use the roundings since they won't be left with a choice and you only have one place to fix a bug or change implementation.


About 2) the logic written in the database is for existing clocking records and in some cases we let the user to edit a clocking record without saving it into the database and we use the rules that are stored in the cache in C# to determine the start and the end for that clocking record on the go.